# RDLC report with column group

Tags: report, rdlc, navision

[image: Screenshot]

I have this code in column `[PSAResPerf_CategoryName]`.

```
=Fields!PSAResPerf_CategoryName.Value / Sum(Fields!PSAResPerf_CategoryName.Value) * 100
```

column `[PSAResPerf_CategoryName]` is a column group.

for example:

we have 4 columns, value are:

- column A: 10
- column B: 5
- column C: 5
- column D: 2

In `column A` I want: ( 10 / 22 ) * 100, but the sum in the column group takes the sum of the same value, so Its always 100%.

Is there a way to get the sum of all the columns before I see them all?

Answer (score 0):

As default Sum calcs for group (in example [PSAResPerf_CategoryName].
Try set scope for SUM(Expression,Scope). In your case - Sum(Fields!PSAResPerf_CategoryName.Value,).
[Sum Function (Visual Studio Report Designer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252113(v=vs.90).aspx)